# Convert string with +00:00 to datetime in Python

Tags: python, formatting, timestamp

I am stuck on how to convert this strong to a datetime object. This is what I tried:

```
import datetime
date_time_str = "2021-07-28 11:19:36.824150+00:00"
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

However, I keep getting the

> ValueError: time data '2021-07-28 11:19:36.824150+00:00' does not match format.

What is the correct format?

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

- `%y` is for 2 digit year
- `%Y` is for 4 digit year

Use `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'`

```
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

---

Or use `fromisoformat`

```
date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time_str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not the timezone, it's the year. You should be using `%Y` instead of `%y`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_time_str = "2021-07-28 11:19:36.824150+00:00"
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
>>> date_time_obj
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 28, 11, 19, 36, 824150, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you used %y instead of %Y
(See reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)

`date_time_str = "2021-07-28 11:19:36.824150+00:00"`
`date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')`